# Он - борется, они - бор(?)тся

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: "борЯтся" или "борЮтся"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

борются, так как образован от глагола бороться - 1 спр.

Answer (score 1):

Они борЮтся.

Answer (score -1):

Глагол I спряжения.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score -1):

Они *борЮтся* - так как образованно от инфинитива *бороться*, а это 1-е спряжение.